# Пунктуация перед союзами между однородными членами

Tags: однородные-члены

Нужна ли запятая или тире в предложениях такого типа: "Он говорил и говорил убедительно", "Он недоумевал и недоумевал справедливо" (когда повторяющийся глагол с последующим наречием уточняет смысл)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна запятая. Она требуется при уточнении. Без неё другой смысл.

*Он говорил и говорил попусту.* = *Он попусту [всё] говорил и говорил.*
*Он говорил, и говорил убедительно.* = Он говорил, и говорил [он] убедительно. || Во второй части сложносочинённого предложения пропущено подлежащее.

Интонационное тире вместо запятой возможно, если автор хочет подчеркнуть важность этого уточнения.

Answer (score 2):

*Он говорил, **и (= причем) говорил убедительно.**  Он недоумевал, **и (= причем) недоумевал справедливо.***

В таких предложениях союз И имеет **присоединительное** значение.

При **усилительном** значении предложение имеет другую структуру с понятной семантикой, связанной с повтором слова:

А сейчас он **говорил и говорил и не мог остановиться.**  [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 3 (1978)]

Он **говорил и говорил**, этот мальчонка, пел, словно птица. [Борис Екимов. Пиночет (1999)]